# How to fix div Alignment in chatbox?

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-alignment, divide

I trying to fix or correct my alignment for my chat box app.
I position 3 div .bubble in a div row .chatlines but it seems to not work (all crowed togerher!). it's hard to explain please see code and example image below.

I would be most grateful for any suggestions or examples to correct my alignment.
thx stewy

[good example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLwGw.jpg)

```css
}   
    body {
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0px;
    
    font-family: Arial;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: .3;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
/*.............. chatlins ..............*/
    
    .chatlines {
    position:fixed;
    min-height: 250px;
    bottom: 110px;
    width: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%); /* center */
}
    .bubble {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    max-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="chatlines">
<div class="bubble" align="left" style="padding-bottom: 10px;height: 60px;">Bubble3</div>
<div class="bubble" align="right" style="padding-bottom: 10px;height: 60px;">Bubble2</div>
<div class="bubble" align="left" style="padding-bottom: 10px;height: 60px;">Bubble1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nth-child` selector with the `margin-left: auto` property on your even numbered `.chatlines` div elements. that will make every other div element inside of chatlines move to the right.

```
div.chatlines div:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Also take note that you will have to remove the absolute positioning in your .bubble class for this to be able to work.